# What is the 'INTERNAL' debug level?

Tags: logging, bug, debug

According to [Setting Debug Log Filters](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/code_setting_debug_log_levels.htm), the debug levels for each category are as follows:

- ERROR
- WARN
- INFO
- DEBUG
- FINE
- FINER
- FINEST

However, when we create a new User Trace Flag (Setup > Logs > Debug Logs > New (User Trace Flags)), using the lookup window's Quick Create button, we get the additional level of "INTERNAL" that sits right between NONE and FINEST.

[image: INTERNAL Debugging Level option]

Even more interesting, when we later go back to edit the Debug Level, we are shown values of NONE, but with everything (?) selected:

[image: NONE Debug Level for most categories]

I've accidentally created the one named INTERNAL shown in the screenshot, as I'm usually just the one to set everything to maximum when I need to find a rather tough problem, but now I'm thinking I should delete it/set it to more appropriate levels, as it may have unintended side effects that I'm not aware of.

The main question here, though, is what does setting this value do, and could it have any harm (besides, of course, creating large debug logs)? Is this some sort of bug, or does it represent some sort of value that would be used by the platform developers?

Comment: The INTERNAL debug level has been in the LogCategoryLevel for the Apex, Metadata, and Tooling APIs for awhile now as a simpleType enumeration. Approximately: Apex - v23.0, Metadata - v.21.0, and Tooling v29.0. I've never seen any advantage over the Finest level when using them. I assumed you need some sort of magic bit in your Org to make the output light up.

Comment: The UI not showing the value correctly is most likely around the Winter 16 changes with having a common DebugLevel for logging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been informed by technical support that R&D has investigated the issue, and that this value will be removed from the UI at some point. As such, we shouldn't use this value for debugging.